# Where should I take some money from after retirement? (IRA, 401K, Roth, Taxable)

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, roth-ira, roth-401k

I have three 401ks, each doing well. One has some pre-1987 money, another has some Roth money, and some has post tax, non Roth money.

I also have several smaller IRAs and Roth IRAs, some of them inherited from my late wife. If I clean too much of this out, I'll start getting fees from my bank because I'd be below their limit.

I do have some other money in taxable investments. But altogether not much. I'm concerned about having easily accessible cash for emergencies.

I'm over 60 and retired, and need to take out some money to do house repairs.

Can any give me some advice on where to take my money from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really hard to tell where *you* should withdraw money from. So instead, I'll give you some pointers to make it easier for you to make the decision for yourself, while keeping the answer useful to others as well.

> I have 3 401ks, ... and some has post tax, non Roth money

1. Why keeping 3 401ks? You can roll them over into an IRA or the one 401k which is still active (I assume here you're not currently employed with 3 different employers). This will also help you avoiding fees for too low balances on your IRAs. However, for the 401k with after tax (not Roth) balance - read the next part carefully.
2. Post tax amounts are your basis. Generally, it is not a good idea to *keep* post-tax amounts in 401k/IRA, you usually do post-tax contributions to convert them to Roth ASAP. Withdrawing from 401k with basis may become a mess since you'll have to account for the basis portion of each withdrawal. Especially if you pool it with IRAs, so that one - don't rollover, keep it separately [to make that accounting easier](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/retirement/05/aftertaxassets.asp).

> I also have several smaller IRAs and Roth IRAs,

1. Keep in mind the [RMD requirements](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/Retirement-Plans-FAQs-regarding-Required-Minimum-Distributions). Roth IRAs don't have those, and are non-taxable income, so you would probably want to keep them as long as possible. This is relevant for 401k as well.
2. Again, consolidating will help you with the fees.

> I'm concerned about having easily accessible cash for emergencies.

I suggest keeping Roth amounts for this purpose as they're easily accessible and bear no taxable consequence. Other than emergencies don't touch them for as long as you can.

> I do have some other money in taxable investments

For those, consider re-balancing to a more conservative style, but beware of the capital gains taxes if you have a lot of gains accumulated. You may want consider [loss-harvesting](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/taxes/08/tax-loss-harvesting.asp) (selling the positions in the red) to liquidate investments without adverse tax consequences while getting some of your cash back into the checking account.

In any case, depending on your tax bracket, capital gains taxes are generally lower (down to 0%) than ordinary income taxes (which is what you pay for IRA/401k withdrawals), so you would probably want to start with these, after careful planning and taking the RMD and the Social Security (if you're getting any) into account.

Comment: Thanks. Your information seems plausible, though the details are always devilish.  For example, how does pre-1987 money in the 401K get treated?  I keep separate 401Ks because all three (I'm now retired) are doing well, and because I was worried that combining them would cause the loss of source information (pre/post-tax,roth,pre-1987) that might be needed later. Similarly, keeping my inherited IRAs/Roths separate from the non-inherited ones was to some advantage, I think. I'd certainly benefit from otherwise combining them as they are each too small to get almost any return.

Comment: Dear @littleadv, I'm in a similar situation with pre-1987 money. Could you add a little to address this? Much thanks for your helpful answer.